# Wordpress: Export posts to csv with data from ACF custom fields

Tags: wordpress, export-to-csv, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to export my posts from a custom post type to a csv file. The point I'd like to get back at later is that my posts have custom fields created using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

I found that this can be done by writing a database query and even found various plugins which could get me all the details. The problem I'm facing is that one of the custom fields in my post is 'Relationship post object' field and whichever method I use to export the posts as CSV give this post object field values as an array. Is there a way to get the actual content as it is outputted on the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

If you output the data for the CSV on the front-end into a table. 
Use this Jquery snippet to create the CSV.

On the front end you need a table and a tag with a class .getfile

Add this to your JS file.

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

    // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
    // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
    tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
    tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

    // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
    colDelim = '","',
    rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

    // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
    csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
        var $row = $(row),
            $cols = $row.find('td');

        return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
            var $col = $(col),
                text = $col.text();

            return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes

        }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

    }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
        .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
        .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

    // Data URI
    csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

    $(this)
        .attr({
        'download': filename,
            'href': csvData,
            'target': '_blank'
    });
}

var now = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date());
var title = $('title').text();
$('.getfile').click(function() { 
    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#DLTable'), 'Exported ' + title + ' ' + now + '.csv']);
});
```

I use ACF too, great plugin. Hope this helps.

Html as requested

```
<h1 class="title">title</h1>
  <a href="#" class="getfile button">Export as CSV</a>          
<table id="DLTable" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>    
     <td> // loop this with ACF repeater field </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @frithir.com. Thanks, will test this out. Quick question, when you said I need a tag with a class .getfile, did you mean an element like a button with the class name .getfile?

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work but this could be because I haven't set it up correctly. Could you paste the sample HTML with a basic table having the class names or IDs?